# Cannot load [app name]: data is newer than client

Tags: quip, liveapps

I'm working on a Quip live app. One user is experiencing this error both in the desktop app as well as in the browser. They see a grey box where the app should appear and

`Cannot load [app name]: data is newer than client`

at the bottom. I'm not sure what that means or where to start looking and I'm not able to reproduce it. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message suggests that the instance of the live app in that document was created with a newer version of the live app than what the current user has access to. The live app is thus not loaded as it might cause data corruption.

This may happen when the live app was added to the document by a beta tester who is using a newer version of the live app, and then that same document is opened by a regular user who is still on an old version.

As a solution, I would suggest having beta testers work in separate, dedicated documents, so that the rest of the users won't run into issues.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. We currently only have 2 Beta versions (no production). There are regular users who have access to a document with an instance of the app but they are able to see and interact with the app. Should that not be the case? 

I think the solution in our case is to publish the app since we are sharing it more widely anyway. Per your suggestion we'll keep beta testers in separate docs. 

Moving forward, aren't we going to run into the same issue if the beta testers and regular users collaborate in a shared doc? What's best practice here?

Comment: Best practice is to keep beta testers in separate documents when testing the app. Whilst technically any user can interact with the live app once added to a doc by a beta tester, it can cause some weird behavior